Warning in curve_fit "Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated"
While fitting the energy spectrum of cobalt for two distinct peaks I am not getting fit parameters and receiving the warning: warnings.warn('Covariance of the parameters could not be estimated'). I'm using the following code:
import numpy as no
from scipy import curve_fit

# Define the Gaussian function
def gaussian(x, a, b, c):
    return a * np.exp(-((x - b) ** 2) / (2 * c ** 2))


# fitting
popt1 , pcov1 = curve_fit(gaussian, channel[450:507], counts[450:507])
popt2, pcov2 = curve_fit(gaussian, channel[507:581], counts[507:581])

print(popt1,popt2)

channel and counts are arrays of integers of length 1024. Any help is highly appreciated.

Maybe normalize the input data to have zero mean and $\text{MSE}=1$, adjusting the parameters after curve fitting.

… that’ll be a start toward specifying the p0= estimates.

As it is right now, your question is off-topic on this site. You are telling us to debug a piece of code that is incomplete for you. Adding the data and a graph of the data might help you to get some hell easier.

Adding to what @Aruralreader mentioned, your data are integers and curve_fit use 1 as default value for the fitted parameters. Scaling your data and choosing some initial values (based on the graph) might help to get better results.

Thank you @nicoguaro, setting initial values worked fine for my case
